# Calculate date before n days of a month

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to calculate a date before 10 days of every month end ?Am using codeigniter platform.

I need to check whether a date is  within 10 days before the end of every month.

Please help

Comment: codeigniter  does not support date manipulation

Comment: Thanks for replying, is there any way in core php

Comment: You may get more assistance if you show what you've already tried. You may also want to reword your question to make it clearer what it is you are actually trying to calculate.

Comment: loop this with 1st days of needed months: `echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-10 days", strtotime("2016-05-01")));`

Comment: Actually i haven't solved yet, i need to check whether a date is  within10 days before the end of every month.I wonder how the logic will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `date_modify` function for example see this php documentation
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Something like this ```$date = (new DateTime('last day of April'))->modify('-10 day');```

Comment: This is working thank you so much. @ Alexander Popov

Answer (score 1):

*i need to check whether a date is within10 days before the end of a month*

```
function testDate($date) {

$uDate = strtotime($date);
return date("m", $uDate) != date("m", strtotime("+10 days", $uDate));
}

echo testDate("2016-03-07") ? "Yes" :"No"; // No
echo testDate("2016-03-27") ? "Yes" :"No"; // Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a library with this

```
class Calculate_days{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function calculate( $to_day = date("j") ){
        $days_month  = date("t");

        $result      = (int) $days_month - $to_day;

        if( $result <= 10){
            $result  = array("type" => TRUE, "missing" => $result . 'days');

            return $result;
        }
        else{
            $result  = array("type" => FASLE, "missing" => $result . 'days');

            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

controller.php

```
function do_somthing(){
    $this->load->library('Calculate_days');

    $result  = $this->Calculate_days->calculate(date("j"));

    var_dump($result);
}
```